# CPU time on multicored/hyperthreaded

Tags: cpu-usage, multicore, hyperthreading

I need to observe the CPU time took by a process in a multicored/hyper-threaded. Suppose a Xeon, Opteron, etc.

Let's assume I have 4 cores, hyper threaded, meaning 8 'virtual' cores.
Let X the program I want to run an observed how much CPU time it took.

- If I run process X in my cpu, I get CPU time A. Suppose A is more than 5 minutes.
- If I run 8 copies of the same process X, I'll get CPU times B1, B2…, B8.
- If I run 7 copies of the same process X, I'll get CPU times C1, C2…, C7.
- If I run 4 copies of the same process X, I'll get CPU times D1, D2…, D4.

QUESTIONs:

1. What's the relationship between numbers A, Bi, Ci, Di?
2. Is A smaller than Bi? How much?
   What about Ci, Di?
3. Are times Bi different between them?
   What about Ci, Di?

Comment: So you write a program which, separately on each thread, calls the `cpu_time` routine a couple of times and reports the data to some output device.  But do be aware that the definition of `cpu_time` is somewhat slippery and not all the major branches of Unix/Linux hold to the same variant.

Comment: Let's assume the program is single threaded. I know cpu_time is measured differently in many context. I'm measuring it in an uniform manner using the same OS and hardware. Now what?

Comment: Rather than make assumptions, make some experiments, get some data, draw some conclusions.

Comment: Yeap, that's my job. Our programs, mostly research related, are single threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the relationship between numbers A, Bi, Ci, Di?

Expect `D1=D2=D3=D4=A*1`, except if you have L2 cache issues (conflicts, faults, ...) where you will have a slightly greater number instead of 1.

Expect `B1=B2=B3=B4=...=B8=A*1.3`. The number `1.3` may vary between `1.1` and `2` depending on you application (certain processor subparts are hyperthreaded, others are not). It was computed from similar statistics, with I give here using the notations of the question: D=23 seconds, and A=18 seconds, according to a private forum. The unthreaded process did integer computations without input/output. Exact application was checking Adem coefficients in algebra of motivic Steenrod (don't know what it is; settings were (2n+e,n) with n=20).

In the case of sevent processes (Cs), if you [assign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3555626/2987828) each process to a core (with /usr/bin/htop on linux), then you will have one of the process (C5 for example) that has the same execution time as an A, and the others (in my example, C1, C2, C3, C4, C6, C7) would have same values than Ds. If you do not assign the processes to cores, and your process lasts enough for the OS do balance them between the cores, they will converge to the mean of the C.

```
Are times Bi different between them? What about Ci, Di?
```

Depend on your OS scheduler and on its configuration. And the percentage shown by `/bin/top` from linux is cheating, it will show nearly 100% for A, Bs, Cs and Ds.

To assess performances, don't [forget](http://techthrob.com/2010/07/21/three-apps-for-monitoring-performance-in-linux/) /usr/bin/nettop (and variants nethogs, nmon, iftop, iptraf), iotop (and variants iostat, latencytop), and collectl (+colmux) and sar (+sag, +sadf).

Comment: Ok, add http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565404/cpu-time-on-multicored-hyperthreaded/20566069#comment30760411_20566069 to your question then notify me here with comment containing @user2987828.

Comment: Do you know that would be the situation is hyprethreading were disabled?

Comment: I saw some experiments reporting `D1=D2=D3=D4=A*1.5` when the HPC assigned tasks to specific virtual cores and hyperthreading was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As 2021, there could be high variations when running multiple experiments. For instance, over 50% of difference.

Two gold standards:

- Run in single-core mode
- Disabling hyperthreading.

For detecting the issue:

- Run the same algorithm multiple times.

In theory this could be used when running experiments:

- Run each experiment k times.

However, this is incomplete when comparing running time as a group of K could in conditions non-comparable with other K experiments.

To alleviate that:

- Run each experiment k times.
- Randomize the order of the experiments.

For publication purposes, that's not enough but it might be useful for fast turn-around, even with k = 2.

H/T: discussion in the slack space of the planning community, related to the conference ICAPS: https://www.icaps-conference.org